# How to remove duplicates the row wherefore two columns matches?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

for my graduation project, I would like to remove duplicate rows and keep only a row where column b and c are equal for the value in column a. I tried a lot of things, groupby, Merge combinations and duplicates, but nothing worked out till now. Can you please help me? Many thanks!

input:

```
   a    b    c
0  1    A    B
1  1    A    A
2  1    A    C
3  2    B    A
4  2    B    B
```

result:

```
   a    b    c
1  1    A    A
4  2    B    B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
print (df)
   a    b    c
0  1    A    B
1  1    A    A
2  1    A    C
3  2    B    A
4  2    B    B
5  3    C    C
6  4    C  NaN
7  4    C    E
7  5  NaN    E
```

Replace `NaN`s by forward and back filling:

```
df1 = df[['b','c']].bfill(axis=1).ffill(axis=1)
print (df1)
   b  c
0  A  B
1  A  A
2  A  C
3  B  A
4  B  B
5  C  C
6  C  C
7  C  E
7  E  E
```

Check condition in `df1` and because same index is possible filter `df`:

```
df = df[df1['b'] == df1['c']]
print (df)
   a    b    c
1  1    A    A
4  2    B    B
5  3    C    C
6  4    C  NaN
7  5  NaN    E
```

Comment: Correct, but when I will have a 6th row, e.g. 3 , C , C, I would like to see that this 6th row will not be removed.

Comment: So the output df will contain row index 1,4 and 5;

Comment: @L.Scheipers - I edit answer with new data and it working nice, for you not?

Comment: @L.Scheipers - Maybe you can add more data in sample for better clarification.

Comment: @L.Scheipers - So what is logic? First select all rows with `b == c` and if in some group is not match select first row of group?

Comment: yeah! all groups( a) have to remain one time, the ones which are duplicate should be removed on the condition (b == c). When b is not known, group a should remain as it should when there is only one row wherfore (b == c).

Comment: @L.Scheipers - I dont understand, can you add more data? Is necessary check between groups by `a` ?